# Significato di "tavoliere" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Mille anni che sto qui*, di Mariolina Venezia, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Stavano passando i **tavolieri** coi dolci e i taralli inceleppati quando se n’erano andati a parlare sotto la luna, dove Aurelio le aveva recitato delle poesie d’amore di cui Albina non aveva capito un’acca.

L'aggettivo "inceleppato" non l'ho trovato su nessun dizionario, ma ho letto in [questo articolo](https://docplayer.it/17822182-Il-lessico-della-narrativa-contemporanea-2002-2006-prove-di-lettura-e-d-inventario.html) che si tratta di un dialettismo. E, infatti, su questo [dizionario etimologico di meridionalismi dell'Università di Nizza](http://sites.unice.fr/site/henneboi/SVG-lirces/langues/real/dialectes/ciato.htm) appare il termine "cileppo" definito  da Rohlfs nel suo *Nuovo Dizionario dialettale della Calabria*, nella variante calabrese *gileppu*, come

> sciroppo denso di zucchero condito con aromi, sughi di frutti ecc. (che serve ad annaspare le paste dolci).

Quindi, immagino che "inceleppato" significhi  imbevuto in questo sciroppo.

La mia domanda, però, è sul significato di "tavolieri" nel testo sopra citato. Ho cercato il termine "tavoliere" in parecchi dizionari, ma le accezioni che ho trovato non sembrano avere senso in questo contesto. Potrebbe trattarsi anche in questo caso di un uso regionale (ma non ne sono per niente sicura). Ecco l'entrata "tavoliere" sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*: [[1]](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000783.jpg) e [[2]](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000784.jpg).

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "tavolieri" nel contesto del passaggio che ho citato?

Comment: Penso  si tratti di grandi vassoi in legno.

Comment: Due ipotesi a livello di logica: 1) Tavolieri sono persone che servono al tavolo (soggetto): i tavolieri stavano passando e servendo. 2) I tavolieri sono oggetti di legno su cui si depongono alimenti (come scrive @Gio) con funzione sintattica di oggetto.

Comment: Secondo me si adatta la definizione 4: "in senso generico tavolo, per lo più di piccole dimensioni". Secondo me è un termine che indica genericamente un tavolo

Comment: Alcune immagini: https://www.google.com/search?q=vassoio+tavoliere&safe=strict&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&prmd=isnv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKk8H78L3oAhVywcQBHdwNCZcQ_AUoAXoECAsQAQ&biw=768&bih=915&dpr=2#imgrc=ygQXj4xM-nuqvM - https://www.google.com/search?q=vassoio+tavoliere&safe=strict&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&prmd=isnv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKk8H78L3oAhVywcQBHdwNCZcQ_AUoAXoECAsQAQ&biw=768&bih=915&dpr=2#imgrc=qJvCOUnv-7bZ-M

Comment: Dalle mie parti, parlando di cibi, *tavoliere* significa un vassoio con diverse varietà di prodotti edibili della stessa categoria, tipicamente affettati o formaggi.

Comment: Per esempio, http://www.soyaepomodoro.com/_include/img/menu/dinner_menu.pdf  (la seconda scelta del menù)

Comment: O forse è più pertinente questo: https://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g194821-d1845556-i99796521-Il_Ristorante_di_Paolo-Menaggio_Lake_Como_Lombardy.html

Comment: Può darsi, @RiccardoDeContardi. Ma un tavolo di piccole dimensioni può essere inteso come un vassoio?

Comment: Personalmente, mi suona di lessico famigliare (o regionale, o di idioletto) dell'autrice.

Comment: Sembrerebbe quasi una variante per rietimologizzazione di “tagliere”.

Comment: Condivido quanto detto da @DaG, per riferirsi alla tavola di legno che fa da base alle portate di formaggi e salumi si usano  anche tagliere, tavogliere e tavoliere.